# How to emulate backspace key as a button in entry widget?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a calculator. I want to add the backspace button. When I try it, it does show backspace in the console but it wont insert the backspaced value (c) in the entry box.
[enter image description here]

I want the program to allow back space. Just the most right value and show the rest in the entry box. For example, if I type 98578 in the entry box, a backspace should change it to 9857. Can someone help?

```
from tkinter import *
import math
window = Tk()
window.minsize(width=300, height=350)
window.title("Scientific Calculator")
def back_space():
    b = input.get()
    c = b + "\b"
    input.delete(0, END)
    print(c)
    input.insert(INSERT, c)

Main_Button = Label(text="CALCULATOR", font=("Times New Roman", 16, "bold"))
Main_Button.pack()
Main_Button.place(x=80,y=5)

input = Entry(window, bd = 10, width=22, fg='black', bg='light blue')
input.place(x=82, y=32)
print(input.get())


button = Button(window, text="⌫", width=3, height=2, fg='black', bg='light 
blue',command=back_space)
button.pack()
button.place(x=200, y=60)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this case it makes sense to use string indicies.

For this to work update your back_space function to this:

```
def back_space():
    b = input.get()
    input.delete(0, END)
    input.insert(0, b[0:-1])
```

This basically takes the value from the entry widget and crops of the last character (or number) of the string.
This is achived using string indicies.

With these string indicies you can select a certain part of a string.
In this case I selected everything of string **b** from index 0 (first character) to the -1th caracter (this is then the first character from the end).
Lastly the second index is not included. Therefore the string is cropped by one digit.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. You saved me a ton of time.

Comment: If you allow the user to move the insertion cursor, this will still always delete the last character rather than delete what the actual backspace key would delete.

Comment: Bryan, correct.

Comment: Very much true! I didn't think of that.
@BryanOakley, as I am new to Stack Overflow (or more precisely to answering questions): Should I now delete my answer as it is marked Correct without it being entierly correct, or can Mohammad just rewoke the "Solved" status and give it to your correct answer?

Comment: @FelixAsenbauer: no, definitely don't delete the answer. If the asker accepts it, then you gave them what they need. In re-reading the question they seem to want to always only delete the last character, so this is fine. It's not a good general-purpose emulation of the backspace key, but it's good for the specific requirements of this question.

Answer (score 1):

Inserting a backspace character is not the solution. What the backspace key actually does is delete the character before the insertion point. You need to get the index of the insertion cursor and then delete the character immediately before it.

```
def back_space():
    insert = int(input.index("insert"))
    if insert > 0:
        input.delete(insert-1)
```

If you always want to delete the last character regardless of the insertion point, use the index of the last character rather than the index of the insertion point:

```
def back_space():
    end = int(input.index("end"))
    if end > 0:
        input.delete(end-1)
```

The advantage to using the `delete` method in this way, rather than getting all of the text, trimming it, and then replacing the original text with the new as shown in other answers, is that this method preserves the location of the insert cursor as well as the selection. Those two get lost of you delete and then replace the entire contents of the entry widget.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def back_space():
    b = input.get()
    c = b[:-1]
    input.delete(0, END)
    print(c)
    input.insert(INSERT, c)
```

Hope this help

Answer (score -1):

You can use the pyautogui module to simulate the backspace key press

Install it on windows using

```
pip install pyautogui
```

Import it to your code

```
import pyautogui
```

then create the 'back_space' function

```
def back_space():
    pyautogui.press('backspace')
```

Full code:

```
from tkinter import *
import math
import pyautogui
window = Tk()
window.minsize(width=300, height=350)
window.title("Scientific Calculator")
def back_space():
    pyautogui.press('backspace')

Main_Button = Label(text="CALCULATOR", font=("Times New Roman", 16, "bold"))
Main_Button.pack()
Main_Button.place(x=80,y=5)

input = Entry(window, bd = 10, width=22, fg='black', bg='light blue')
input.place(x=82, y=32)
print(input.get())


button = Button(window, text="⌫", width=3, height=2, fg='black', bg='light blue',command=back_space)
button.pack()
button.place(x=200, y=60)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work. If I type '1234' in the input field and then press the button, nothing changes. The input field still has '1234'.

Comment: I tested it and it worked, make sure you click the entry field before you start typing

Comment: I did. I clicked, I typed a few characters, then clicked the button. I'm on OSX, so maybe that's a contributing factor. Plus, this answer seems like overkill - you require a large module to do something that tkinter can do natively.

Comment: he said he wanted to "emulate" the key press, maybe it will only work on windows

Comment: you can use from pyautogui import press